# Database design - system default items and custom user items

Tags: database, database-design

This question applies to any database table design, where you would have system default items and custom user defaults of the same type (ie user can add his own custom items/settings).

Here is an example of invoicing and paymenttypes, By default an invoice can have payment terms of DueOnReceipt, NET10, NET15, NET30 (this is the default for all users!) therefore you would have two tables "INVOICE" and "PAYMENT_TERM"

```
INVOICE
Id
...
PaymentTermId



PAYMENT_TERM (System default)
Id
Name
```

Now what is the best way to allow a user to store their own custom "PaymentTerms" and why? (ie user can use system default payment terms OR user's own custom payment terms that he created/added)

Option 1) Add UserId to PaymentTerm, set userid for the user that has added the custom item and system default userid set to null.

```
INVOICE
Id
...
PaymentTermId



PaymentTerm
Id
Name
UserId (System Default, UserId=null)
```

Option 2) Add a flag to Invoice "IsPaymentTermCustom" and Create a custom table "PAYMENT_TERM_CUSTOM"

```
INVOICE
Id
...
PaymentTermId
PaymentTermCustomId
IsPaymentTermCustom (True for custom, otherwise false for system default)

PaymentTerm
Id
Name

PAYMENT_TERM_CUSTOM
Id
Name
UserId
```

Now check via SQL query if the user is using a custom payment term or not, if IsPaymentTermCustom=True, it means the user is using custom payment term otherwise its false.

Option 3) ????

...

Comment: Can you explain the user experience flow more? How does the user actually select a 'custom' payment term? When they navigate through the checkout process and about to submit an invoice?

Comment: When the user creates an invoice, the user can select the "PaymentTerms", system default payment termss are loaded into a drop list, user can select the default payment terms OR add a new payment term, (his own), so next time the drop list will load the system default and the user's payment terms.

Comment: If a particular user creates a PaymentTerm can everyone else use it, or just them?

Comment: @WW just the single user that created the payment term, hence UserId will equal to the owner of the payment term.

Comment: Do the details for system default payment terms for change later on?  Like change the terms of NET10 starting 1/1/2012?  If so, would that be a new system payment type, or would the old one get updated along with all previous invoices?  Could new terms come in and old terms go inactive?  Is there other data associated with PAYMENT_TERM?  Invoices are tied to specific UserIDs, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a general rule:

- Prefer adding columns to adding tables
- Prefer adding rows to adding columns

Generally speaking, the considerations are:

#### Effects of adding a table

- Requires the most changes to the app: You're supporting a new kind of "thing"
- Requires more complicated SQL: You'll have to join to it somehow
- May require changes to *other* tables to add a foreign key column referencing the new table
- Impacts performance because more I/O is needed to join to and read from the new table

Note that I am not saying "never add tables". Just know the costs.

#### Effects of adding a column

- Can be expensive to add a column if the table is large (can take hours for the `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` to complete and during this time the table wil be locked, effectively bringing your site "down"), but this is a one-time thing
- The cost to the project is low: Easy to code/maintain
- Usually requires minimal changes to the app - it's a new aspect of a thing, rather than a new thing
- Will perform with negligible performance difference. Will not be measurably worse, but may be a lot faster depending on the situation (if having the new column *avoids* joining or expensive calculations).

#### Effects of adding rows

- Zero: If your data model can handle your new business idea by just adding more rows, that's the best option

(Pedants kindly refrain from making comments such as "there is no such thing as 'zero' impact", or "but there will still be more disk used for more rows" etc - I'm talking about *material* impact to the DB/project/code)

To answer the question: **Option 1 is best** (i.e. add a column to the payment option table).
The reasoning is based on the guidelines above and this situation is a good fit for those guidelines.

Further,
I would also store "standard" payment options in the *same* table, but with a `NULL` userid; that way you only have to add new payment options when you *really* have one, rather than for *every* customer even if they use a standard one.

It also means your invoice table does *not* need changing, which is a good thing - it means minimal impact to that part of your app.

Comment: I would like to know why that option would be better than option 2 ?

Comment: Option 1 is better, because you can get both standard and user-specific payment terms with a single (and simple) database query.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that there are merely "Payment Terms" and "Users". The decision of what are the "Default" payment terms is a business rule, and therefore would be best represented in the business layer of your application.

Assuming that you would like to have a set of pre-defined "default" payment terms present in your application from the start, these would already be present in the payment terms table. However, I would put a reference table in between USERS and PAYMENT TERMS:

```
USERS:
    user-id
    user_namde

USER_PAYMENT_TERMS:
    userID
    payment_term_id

PAYMENT_TERMS:
    payment_term_id
    payment_term
```

Your business layer should offer up to the user (or more likely, the administrator) through a GUI the ability to:

1. Assign 0 to many payment term options to a particular user (some
   users may not want one of the defaults to even be available, for
   example.
2. Add custom payment terms, which then become available for assignment to one or more users (but which avoids the creation of duplicate payment terms by different users)
3. Allows the definition of a custom payment term to be assigned to more than one user (say the user's company a unique payment process which requires all of their users to utilize a payment term other than one of the defaults? Create the custom term once, and assign to all users.

Your application business layer would establish rules governing access to payment terms, which could then be accessed by your user interface.

Your UI would then (again, likely through an administrator function) allow the set up of one or more payment terms in addition to the standards you describe, and then make them available to one or more users through something like a checked list box (for example).
[image: Hacked together sample (I'm using VS 2010, but you get the idea . . .)]

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is definately better for the following reasons:-

Correctness

- You can implement a database constraint for uniqueness of the payment term name
- You can implement a foreign key constraint from Invoice to PaymentTerm

Ease of Use

- Conducting queries will be much simplier because you will always join from Invoice to PaymentTerm rather than requiring a more complex join.  Most of the time when you select you will not care if it is an inbuilt or custom payment term.  The optimizer will have an easier time with a normal join instead of one that depends on another column to decide which table to join.
- Easier to display a list of PaymentTerms coming from one table

We use Option 1 in our data-model quite alot.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem, as I see it, is that different payment terms lead to different calculations, too. If I were still in the welding supply business, I'd want to add "2% 10 NET 30", which would mean 2% discount if the payment is made in full within 10 days, otherwise, net 30."

Setting that issue aside, I think ownership of the payment terms makes sense.  Assume that the table of users (not shown) includes the user "system" as, say, user_id 0.

```
create table payment_terms (
  payment_term_id integer primary key,
  payment_term_owner_id integer not null references users (user_id),
  payment_term_desc varchar(30) not null unique,
);

insert into payment_terms values (1, 0, 'Net 10');
insert into payment_terms values (2, 0, 'Net 15');
...
insert into payment_terms values (5, 1, '2% 10, Net 30');
```

This keeps foreign keys simple, and it makes it easy to select payment terms at run time for presentation in the user interface.

Be very careful here. You *probably* want to store the *description*, not the ID number, with your invoices.  (It's unique; you can set a foreign key reference to it.) If you store only the ID number, updating a user's custom description might subtly corrupt all the data that references it.

For example, let's say that the user created a custom payment term number 5, '2% 10, Net 30'.  You store the ID number 5 in your table of invoices.  Then the user decides that things will be different starting today, and updates that description to '2% 10, Net 20'. Now on all your past invoices, the arithmetic no longer matches the payment terms.

Your auditor will kill you. Twice.

You'll want to prevent ordinary users from deleting rows owned by the system user. There are several ways to do that.

- Use a BEFORE DELETE trigger.
- Add another table with foreign key references to the rows owned by the system user.
- Restrict all access through stored procedures that prevent deleting system rows.

(And flags are almost never the best idea.)

Comment: Not quite. a) No nulls. b) Unique descriptions. c) Invoices use a foreign key to the unique description. (I probably wouldn't use a payment_term_id at all if I were designing it.)

Answer (score 0):

Applying general rules of database design to the problem at hand:

- one table for system payment terms
- one table for user payment terms
- a view of join of the two above

Now you can join invoice on the view of payment terms.

Benefits:

- No flag columns
- No nulls
- You separate system defaults from user data
- Things become straight forward for the db